# How to hide a column on Material UI based on certain criteria?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a datagrid using MUI and I have came across a use case where I need to hide one of the columns if I do not have a certain role. Here is the code.

```
const hideColumn = () => {
        const globalAdmin = auth.verifyRole(Roles.Admin);

        if(!globalAdmin){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };


const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 100 },
        { field: 'name',
          headerName: 'Client code',
          flex: 1,
          hide: hideColumn,
          renderCell: (params) => {
                    
                    return params.getValue("name");
            },
        },
];
```

I'm confused on why this is not working. If I just use `hide:true` or `hide:false` it works but I need have an if statement to check the credentials first and this can't be done in the `renderCell` (or at least I can't get it to work). Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should call it as function `hide: hideColumn()`

Comment: As an addition, if `hideColumn()` is called then it's only effective on the first render. The state should be stored with a hook or similar to render dynamically. However. this state does not persist after each reload.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a function to retrieve your columns and pass props to this function. Then you just have to push your columns according to criteria:

```
export default function getColumns (product, isHide, t) {
let columns = [
    {
      field: 'organizationName',
      headerName: headerNameOrganization,
      flex: 0.3,
    },
 ]
  if (!product) {
    columns.push(
      {
        field: 'status',
        headerName: headerNameStatus,
        flex: 0.2,
        filterable: false,
  })
}
return columns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the prop `columnVisibilityModel` of `<DataGrid />` to control the column visibility *dynamically*.

The prop can also have a listener.

> You can use the `onColumnVisibilityModelChange` prop to listen to the changes to the visible columns and update the prop accordingly.
> ([MUI doc](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#controlled-visible-columns))

At first, I was using the `initialState` (as the ff), but MUI said [in their documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/state/#direct-selector-access):

> The `initialState` can only be used to set the initial value of the state, the grid will not react if you change the `initialState` value later on.
>
> If you need to fully control specific models, use the control props instead...

```
<DataGrid
  columns={columns}
  rows={rows}
  loading={!users.length}
  initialState={{
      columns: {
          columnVisibilityModel: {
              myColumn1: isAdmin(user),
              myColumn2: isAdmin(user),
          },
     },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const columnVisibilityModel = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      your_Column_Name_Field_Key: false, // False to hide, true by default
    }
  }, [your_Dependency_Variable_Comes_here]);
```

**Note:** you can replace false with your condition which returns true or false

```
  <DataGrid
    ...
    columnVisibilityModel={columnVisibilityModel} // Add this
  />
```

**Ref:**
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#disable-the-column-visibility-panel